# Difficulty running crontab startup script

Tags: docker, cron

I have the following crontab job to run on reboot:

```
PATH=/snap/bin:/usr/bin
@reboot run_me_startup.sh >> $HOME/startup_run_log.txt 2>&1
```

My docker install has placed the files in /snap/bin (hence my PATH statement).  My run_me_startup.sh script is as follows:

```
echo "Startup Script"
sleep 240
echo "Running..."
sudo service apache2 stop && sudo service nginx stop
sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /var/run/docker.sock
/snap/bin/docker network create dbnet
/snap/bin/docker network create nginx_network
export aws_access_key_id="secret"
export aws_secret_access_key="secret"
cd $HOME/The6ix/The6ixDjango && pwd && /snap/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down --remove-orphans
{
{
rm -rf $HOME/The6ix/The6ixDjango && cd $HOME/The6ix && git clone https://secret@github.com/cooneycw/The6ixDjango.git 
} ||
{
cd $HOME/The6ix && git clone https://secret@github.com/cooneycw/The6ixDjango.git
}
}
ls
cp $HOME/database.env $HOME/The6ix/The6ixDjango/database.env
```

I inserted the sleep 240 to ensure that the docker service was started before the code executes.  My output log is as follows:

```
Startup Script
Failed to stop nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not loaded.
chown: cannot access '/var/run/docker.sock': No such file or directory
/home/ubuntu/run_me_startup.sh: 4: docker: not found
/home/ubuntu/run_me_startup.sh: 5: docker: not found
/home/ubuntu/The6ix/The6ixDjango
/home/ubuntu/run_me_startup.sh: 8: docker-compose: not found
Cloning into 'The6ixDjango'...
The6ixDjango
/home/ubuntu/run_me_startup.sh: 19: docker-compose: not found
/home/ubuntu/run_me_startup.sh: 20: docker-compose: not found
/home/ubuntu/run_me_startup.sh: 21: docker-compose: not found
/home/ubuntu/run_me_startup.sh: 22: docker-compose: not found
/bin/sh: 1: run_me_startup.sh: not found
/bin/sh: 1: run_me_startup.sh: not found
/bin/sh: 1: run_me_startup.sh: not found
/bin/sh: 1: run_me_startup.sh: not found
/bin/sh: 1: run_me_startup: not found
/bin/sh: 1: run_me_startup: not found
/bin/sh: 1: run_me_startup.sh: not found
```

I don't understand why I am getting the docker: not found errors with the PATH statement in my crontab.  And should I be concerned about the /bin/sh notes at the bottom of my log?  Have I somehow triggered my script to run twice?  Linux novice...I appreciate your generosity!

Comment: Try giving a full path to `run_me_startup.sh` in crontab, but also doublecheck that `/snap/bin` (or `/snap` or whatever) is actually mounted when the script runs.

Comment: I just did "mountpoint /snap/bin" where docker is located and it returns "/snap/bin is not a mountpoint".

Comment: OK, is /snap a mountpoint?

Comment: "/snap is not a mountpoint"

Comment: Standard debugging advice: add an `ls -laR /snap/` statement into the shell script, plus other commands like `echo $varname` to see what's going on. Basically, print as much debugging info as possible

Comment: I will try this..thanks.  I'm uninstalling the snap version of docker and utilizing /usr/bin version instead as well.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I did not realize that my log was additive (I thought it would be re-built each time).  So my cron job was not actually finding my script (hence the repetitive items).

More importantly, snap is garbage and created a multitude of issues I had to resolve (installed the docker.io version through apt) and my script is now executing correctly.